# randomly generating unique number between 1-999 for primary key in table

Tags: sql, sqlite, lua

I have a problem I'm not sure how to solve elegantly.

**Background Information**

I have a table of widgets.  Each widget is assigned an ID from a range of numbers, let's say between 1-999. The values of 1-999 is saved in my database as "lower_range" and "upper_range" in a table called "config". 
When a user requests to create a new widget using my web app, I need to be able to do the following:

- generate a random number between 1 and 999 using lua's math.random function or maybe a random number generator in sqlite (So far, in my tests, lua's math.random always returns the same value...but that's a different issue)
- do a select statement to see if there already is a widget with this number assigned...
- if not, create the new widget.
- otherwise repeat process until you get a number that is not currently in use.

**Problem**

The problem I see with the above logic is two-fold:

1. the algorithm can potentially take a long time because I have to keep searching until I find a unique value.
2. How do I prevent simultaneous requests for new widget numbers generating the same value?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Why can't your ID's be a series? Why do they have to be random?

Comment: That's requirement from end user.  It'd be a lot easier if sequential.  Then i could keep track of next available number in the config table.  But they want random.

Comment: Can you use GUID's, then? If you keep generating them in the same machine, I think you won't get a key collision before the heat death of the universe. They're not numerical but hey, problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate your random numbers ahead of time and store them in a table; make sure the numbers are unique. Then when you need to get the next number, just check how many have already been assigned and get the next number from your table. So, instead of

- Generate a number between 1-999
- Check if it's already assigned
- Generate a new number, and so on.

do this:

- Generate array of 999 elements that have values 1-999 in some random order
- Your `GetNextId` function becomes `return ids[currentMaxId+1]`

To manage simultaneous requests, you need to have some resource that generates a proper sequence. The easiest is probably to use a key in your widget table as the index in the `ids` array. So, add a record to the `widgets` table first, get its key and then generate widget ID using `ids[key]`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table to store the keys and the 'used' property.

```
CREATE TABLE KEYS
  ("id" INTEGER, "used" INTEGER)
;
```

Then use the following to find a new key

```
select id
from KEYS
where used = 0
order by RANDOM()
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't generate a random number, just pick the number off a list that's in random order.

For example, make a list of numbers 1 - 999.  Shuffle that list using [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) or equivalent (see also [Randomize a List in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273313/427192) even if you're not using C#).

Now you can just keep track of the most recently used index into your list.  (Shuffling the list should occur exactly once, then you store and reuse the result).

Rough pseudo-code:

```
If config-file does not contain list of indices
    create a list with numbers 1 - 999
    Use Fisher-Yates to shuffle that list
    // list now looks like 0, 97, 251, 3, ...
    Write the list to the config file
    Set 'last index used' to 0 and write to config file
end if
```

To use this,

```
NextPK = myList[last-index-used]
last-index-used = last-index-used + 1
write last-index-used to config file
```

Comment: thanks dan.  i might be misreading but is your answer prety much the same as paul kulchenkos?  just trying to understand what my options are...

Comment: Yep, they're pretty much the same.  I'm not sure why I didn't think to store the list of indices in the database.  If it's an option, it'd probably be easier to implement.

Comment: I appreciate your answer though and the mention of fisher-yates shuffle. learned something new!  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To get and flag an ID as used at same time (expanding on Declan_K's answer):

replace into random_sequence values ((select id from random_sequence where used=0 order by random()), 1);

select id from random_sequence where rowid = last_insert_rowid();
6

When you run out of "unused" sequence table entries the select will return "blank"

I use replace into as update doesn't have an last_insert_rowid() equiv that I can see.

Answer (score -2):

You Can get sql to create a primary key, that will increase by one evert time you add a ros to the database.

Comment: OP stated twice that his keys must be random.

Comment: the widget id is not just a pk that's incremented sequentially.  it must be a number between a pre-defined range, and cannot be assigned sequentially.