# Random number in table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, random

Please help me

```
    CREATE TABLE UNIVERSITY
    (
      ID INT,
      FirstName nvarchar(100),
      LastName nvarchar(100)
    )
```

Need that the ID is automatically taken randomly always different numbers. It must be 10 numbers wihout any logic.

Example:

```
5478596256  Bob  Brown
9852451254  Tom  Jones
7078596585  Jason  Sadler
```

Comment: Already answered, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447254/randomly-generating-unique-number-between-1-999-for-primary-key-in-table/16447477#16447477

Comment: Does it really have to be a random number? why not use a sequential ID? Guaranteed to be unique, and it's something built in. Another option is GUID, but then, i'ts not an integer. I'm assuming it must be an integer based on your table definition.

Comment: @StealthRabbi thank you for ansewring. can you give me small code for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating a [unique, sequential ID](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1600/auto-generated-sql-server-keys-with-the-uniqueidentifier-or-identity/).

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
      -- Start at 1 and increment by 1
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
      FirstName nvarchar(100),
      LastName nvarchar(100)
)
```

Another option would be to create a uniqueidentifier (GUID)

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
      ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() ROWGUIDCOL PRIMARY KEY,
      FirstName nvarchar(100),
      LastName nvarchar(100)
)
```

Personally, I like Sequential ID. It's easier to debug a key if it's a simple integer rather than an unwieldy guid. Manually punching in SQL for testing/debugging is very frustuarting when having to punch in a GUID and get the formatting correct.  Also, a sequential ID gives you another way of looking at record order. But this may depend on your specific application needs. Also, a sequential ID is more universal than a GUID. GUID is somewhat of a Microsoft-ism, and while they can be stored in other DBs such as Oracle, the order of the bytes is unique to SQL Server, and doesn't port easily.

Also, just a hunch, but sequential integer IDs may have better performance with indexing.

Comment: You are quite welcome. If you feel this adequately answer your question, please mark it as answered so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is for a unique 10 digit number for every record, with no logic, then this will do it. Additionally, you may want to consider using `BIGINT`instead of `INT` for your `ID` column since you would already be starting off at 1 billion per the 10 digit requirement.  The upper limit for the `INT` data type is `2147483647`.

```
CREATE TABLE UNIVERSITY
(
    ID          INT IDENTITY(1000000000, 1) PRIMARY KEY
   ,FirstName   NVARCHAR(100)
   ,LastName    NVARCHAR(100)
)
```